# Kali Linux on portable SSD with data persistence

Tags: linux, kali-linux, ssd, portability, persistence

I need to setup a portable kali-linux environment that I can boot on any available computer. I don't want to use a virtual environment because I would need to download VMware on the host computer, plus it's not practical since I will need to boot my OS on friends/customers computers. I just want to boot it from the BIOS, do what I have to do and leave without changing or downloading any files/software on machines that aren't mine. I want to leave the hosts like I was never there after I'm done.

Of course, I need data persistence so that I can access, change and keep my datas across reboots on different machines.

So, if I'm not wrong, what I need is:

[Adding Persistence to a Kali Linux Live USB Drive](https://www.kali.org/docs/usb/usb-persistence/)

[Making a Kali Bootable USB Drive (Windows)](https://www.kali.org/docs/usb/live-usb-install-with-windows/)

I have two questions:

- Wouldn't something like that run too slow on a [classic USB flash drive](https://www.samsung.com/us/computing/memory-storage/usb-flash-drives/usb-3-1-flash-drive-bar-plus-256gb-titan-gray-muf-256be4-am/)?
- I kind of want to use a portable SSD for this. I found [one that I like](https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/product/portable/t7-touch/) and I'd like your opinions on it and if what I want to do with it is possible. Since this SSD has built-in features and software, is it going to be a problem to make it a kali-linux portable environment? For example, what if I need to format the disk to a specific file system type?

Comment: Why not make a bootable CD/DVD/USB image to boot from, and then use a USB "thumbdrive"/SSD for persistent storage? As you are trying, you will likely face the biggest problem with solid state storage (be it USB or SSD): A limited lifetime of write cycles. It is usually in the \*illions of cycles, but if you use the drive often enough, you will smash in to it. Easier to use a LIVE style bootable CD/DVD/USB, do what you need, and only plug in persistent storage when it is needed.

Answer (score 0):

For a persistent Kali linux install, this will be plenty fast. My only concern would be the security software that is on this device. I seem to be finding mixed opinions across different forums regarding the t5 and t7 devices. I would consider saving some money and getting a smaller stick if you can get by with less storage space.

This device is great [Samsung USB 256](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07D7Q41PM). You could then always utilize something like the t7 for extra storage.